# core data, storing images in a dictionary

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage, nsmutabledictionary

I have an app that feature "pages". Each page can have n number of images, depending on user preference. To store the images and associate the image with the correct view etc, I am building a dictionary for each image, then storing that dictionary in an array of image dictionaries, which I save to core data as binary data. I am storing the image itself as an object in the dictionary, like below. Is this an efficient and safe way to do this? Seems to work ok...

```
imageDictionay = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image, @"image", imageTag, @"tag", imageTransformString, @"transform", nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That way will certainly work, but I would personally create another entity for ImageInfo like so:

[image: Graphic Editor]

[image: Standard Editor]

If you are going to have a dictionary with the same three keys, it makes more sense to me to have an entity with those three attributes.

Also, if you are really worried about performance, you could also write the image to disk and just put a string in Core Data to tell you where the image is stored.

Comment: Saw your answer after I posted mine so I deleted. You did a good job with the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar to this. Turned out to be easier than what I was doing anyway.